# sprite kit editor IK simulation

Tags: sprite-kit

Trying to make a IK chain of a few simple sprite nodes in the scene editor.

In the WWDC demo it looked like a case of parenting the nodes in their proper order, selecting the chained nodes and running in Simulator mode. The cursor changed to a cross hair and dragging in the window made the IK chain moved as expected.

I have added the sprite nodes in the editor, adjusted pivots and IK angle limits. However I cannot find how to activate the "Simulate" mode in the scene editor, a mode which all the demos and online reference mention. There is only Animate and Layout which seem to be the reverse of each other as Animate is where items can be added and manipulated and Layout is where it plays back.

Can an IK chain be constructed solely in the scene editor or do the constraints need to be created in code which would then allow the Simulate mode to work in the editor?

(xcode v7.2.1 on osX 10.10)

edit: Looking at the demo again: it seems like a hot key or modifier activates the IK drag mode, the cursor changes and then arm parts move, but I cannot find anything that switches to that active drag mode. Clicking always deselects the nodes I am trying to IK drag. Looks like something simple but I can find no reference for it in the docs or forums...

**tl;dr:  How does one make and test IK chains interactively in the xcode scene editor?**

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't in the playground?

Comment: Pretty sure... [WWDC 2014 - Session 606 - OS X, iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014/606/)    around 44:10 showing off Scene Editor...

Comment: The demo of Scene Editor has robot made of sprite nodes with arm nodes parented from shoulder to wrist (claw). Demo'er activates "Simulate", selects the arm nodes, cursor changes and then dragging moves arm ik.   I do not have a "Simulate" instead it toggles between Animate and Layout. I am guessing this is just a version update rename situation, but the IK still doesn't behave as shown.

Comment: Yes simulate became animate

Comment: Layout is the state of laying items down. Animate is the state if animating/simulating.  That button just toggles the state

Comment: That sounds right, so it seems strange that play back starts when toggling to Layout and that I can only add new objects when it is set to Animate.

Comment: The button does not tell you what state you are in, pushing the button changes the state,  that is like you dont push the on button to turn something off

Comment: Ah, ok. I was interpreting undecorated text in a section header as a descriptor and not as a button, now I get it. Any idea as how to get the IK to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an [answer here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-whats-new-in-spritekit-part-2--cms-22465), cannot believe this was not easier to find in the Apple docs.

So it is just a key combo: To test the IK hold **Shift-Control-Click** while in Animate/Simulate mode.